# Optimizing UDF - Is Using DUAL Expensive

Tags: oracle, tuning, functions

I am new to Oracle technology (primarily versed in SQL Server) and I am having trouble with the performance of a UDF.

The purpose of the UDF is to take some inputs for an "event", and look up an "expected time for event b to occur". The function returns a single `DATE` value.

The first thing that occurs is a `SELECT ... INTO [variable] FROM DUAL;` a variable. Finally a lookup occurs in a reference table (only ~30k rows), and that is stored in the return variable.

It took 8 hours to process on 800k rows. I can select all of the columns without using the function in less than 40 seconds.

My main question is: Is the use of DUAL costing me?

We are on an Oracle 11g RAC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ivan said, your problem is not with dual specifically.  However, the context switch required to switch between PL/SQL and SQL is slowing things down.  Often, SELECT statements like this can be converted into simple PL/SQL assignments.  If that isn't possible, perhaps the logic can be moved into the later look up.

Something else you could consider is doing a join with your reference table outside of the UDF.

Before doing anything though, you should consider profiling the function with [DBMS_PROFILER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_profil.htm#sthref6972).  This will show you what part of the function to focus on for your tuning.

Answer (score 1):

No. Oracle knows that DUAL is "in-memory" table. Your problem is somewhere else.

BTW: you can also use `call fname(...);` statement.